Is it possible to use cat with execl inside a c program to print out its code without knowing the file path
As a part of my asigment i have to print out the source code of my c program using the cat command which needs to be coded into the code itself.I have understood that I need to use some variation of the execl function to achieve that but what is bothering me is that to do that I need to know the path of my file which could change, so i was wondering if there is a way to find the path of the file inside the program.
I tried running the pwd command to find my current path but i couldnt get it to store the result in a variable and i dont know why execl("/bin/pwd", "pwd", NULL);. Also the program is executed in linux if that helps.

Why can't you use the getcwd function? Perhaps you need to take a step back, and read some tutorials and beginners material about systems-programming in Linux?

When the program starts the argv[0] string contains the path to the executable. But that may be completely different to the location of the source file. However, if it is guaranteed to be the same, you can use that information to locate the source.

"i have to print out the code of my program into the terminal using the cat command." so cat source.c?

Are you referring to the source code or the binary executable code?

Can you please copy-paste (as text) the full and complete assignment/exercise into your question?

Can you use the #embed functionality of C23?  You might be able to determine the source file name at compile time and then embed it as a string in the compiled binary,

Thanks for the help guys, i ended up using the getcwd thank you for showing it to me as i didnt know it existed. This is the algorythm i used to print out the source code


        //Getting the file path//
        getcwd(cwd, sizeof(cwd));
        strcat(cwd,"/test.c");
        //printing the code using the cat command through the execl function//
        execl("/bin/cat", "cat", cwd, NULL);


If you want to refer to a file in the current working directory just refer to test.c without any / or directory name at all.

Separately, are you quite sure this is what your assignment meant you to do? Writing a quine is a common exercise, but referring to your source file at runtime is generally considered cheating.

@CharlesDuffy, the question does specifically say that the exercise is to print out the source using cat.  I'm therefore guessing that the point of the exercise is execve use, and that quineness is ancillary.

@JohnBollinger, ...if the OP wasn't pulling a XY-question and asking about a problem they encountered while implementing their own solution, a step removed from the original assignment. Since quines are a common exercise, I don't think it was unreasonable to ask.

You can use __FILE__ macro to find the file even if you are executing it from a different directory

@CharlesDuffy you are correct with your observation. I corrected it in my program so that it would get the name of the file name on its own.

@DiegoTorresMilano yeah i found about that macro later but I'd rather find a way to code it in myself if possible thats why i did it like this, although it overcomplicates it.

But it's not the same thing, FILE gives you the path to the source no matter where you are executing from while getcwd() it's a runtime value


what is bothering me is that to do that I need to know the path of my file which could change

That's a reasonable concern, but I suspect you're thinking ahead of the assignment (good for you!).
There is no inherent connection between your program's C source file and any executable(s) built from it.  I am therefore inclined to guess that you're meant to make some assumptions, such as:

that the working directory when you run the program is the same as the working directory when you built it, AND

that the source file is not moved, renamed, or deleted between program build and program execution.


With those particular assumptions, you can locate the source file to cat at the same relative path you used to build it, which you could hardcode into the program.  Do consult your instructor if you're uncertain about this.

I tried running the pwd command to find my current path

If ever you need to determine your current working directory then you should use the getcwd() function.  But if you make the kind of assumptions described above then you shouldn't need that.

Alternate possibility: pass the file path of your source code to the program as argument.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main( int argc, char ** argv )
{
  // No argument? No go!
  if (argc != 2) return 1;

  // Run cat for the argument file
  execl( "/bin/cat", "/bin/cat", argv[1], (char*)NULL );

  // If we get here then execl() failed
  return 1;
}

Now you can compile your program and run it as:
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic-errors -O3 a.c
$ ./a.out a.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main( int argc, char ** argv )
{
  // No argument? No go!
  if (argc != 2) return 1;

  // Run cat for the argument file
  execl( "/bin/cat", "/bin/cat", argv[1], (char*)NULL );

  // If we get here then execl() failed
  return 1;
}
$


It depends on how you compile your program. If you use gcc, you probably get your binary file next to your source code. Instead of executing pwd, you should use getcwd function (as pointed out by @Some programmer dude). Don't forget to run your program in directory with source code.
#include <stdlib.h>                    
#include <string.h>                                                             
#include <unistd.h>                                                             
#include <linux/limits.h>                                                       
                                                                                
#define YOUR_FILE "test.c"                                                      
                                                                                
int main() {                                                                                                                                    
        char cwd[PATH_MAX];                                                     
        getcwd(cwd, sizeof(cwd));                                               
        char* destination;                                                      
        int chars = strlen(cwd) + strlen(YOUR_FILE);                            
        chars += 3;                                                             
        destination = malloc(sizeof(char)*chars);                               
        memcpy(destination, cwd, sizeof(char)*chars);                           
        strcat(destination, "/");                                               
        strcat(destination, YOUR_FILE);                                         
        execl("/bin/cat", "/bin/cat", destination, NULL);                       
        free(destination);                                                      
        return 0;                                                               
}


(a) free(FILE) is wrong. (b) Not enough space is allocated for the directory, a slash, the file name, and the terminating null character. (c) Building a path containing the current working directory is unnecessary since it is the default for opening a file. (d) This does not conform to the stated requirement of using the cat command.

Sorry for broken code, now it should be OK
